# Organizing Chef cookbooks

Tags: chef, repository

Is it 100% required to store all the cookbooks under `chef-repo`? This seems a little bit inconvenient for me, I'd prefer to store solution cookbooks in the application codebase, or just as a standalone git repos.

I know that tools like `knife` rely on configuration files to be present in `.chef`, and it frustrates me a little bit too.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, it is not, the chef-repo is the legacy way back to chef 10.

Knife allows working on multiples directory with the -o option. Berks work from current directory.

You can also work around the default .chef directory by using the `KNIFE_HOME` environment variable too.

The current recomendations is indeed a repo per cookbook (or alongside another app)

Comment: But there is still a [page about it in the docs](https://docs.chef.io/chef_repo.html). Am I reading the right docs? Also, by any change, maybe you know, if I use [Vagrant and Chef Zero](https://www.vagrantup.com/docs/provisioning/chef_zero.html) to manually test my cookbooks, how do I manage [data bags](https://www.vagrantup.com/docs/provisioning/chef_zero.html#data_bags_path), [cookbooks](https://www.vagrantup.com/docs/provisioning/chef_zero.html#cookbooks_path) and other policies then?

Comment: The docs are not always up to date, I'm afraid the way to manage things would be better discussed on chef's slack btw

Comment: @madhead I just realized I had forgot a point, I've updated the answer and the slack channel join page is here http://community-slack.chef.io (please forgive the formatting, I'm on phone)

Comment: Man, you've answered almost all the question I had recently. I understood more about Chef then in previous year. Thanks for that!

Comment: @madhead feel free to join the slack channel, I'm there too but there's people far more advanced than me and some folks from Chef company also who are really helpful :)